# Setting Up Lynx As A Web Browser On Windows - Proxy Mess

Tags: http-proxy, web

I need to use Lynx on my machine - The only problem is the company has a proxy which they force us to use and cannot be by passed

I have had a look at lynx.cfg but I do not understand how to force it to use the proxy

Can anyone help please?

I am using Windows

Comment: lucid lynx and lynx are different. I'd edit the tags if i had the rep.Lucid lynx - ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Ok, done! My first official act as a 500-rep club member. ;-) Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Add a line like this to your lynx.cfg file:

`http_proxy:http://your.proxy.com:port/`